# Run protobuf given example on eclipse (C++)

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, protocol-buffers

I am trying to use and understand the protocol buffers. I have installed the library and tried running the example. but I am unable to see where I am going wrong.

Below I am describing all the steps:
**1.** Follow the instructions to install protobuf compiler https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/tree/master/src

**2.** Follow the instructions to install protobuf plug-in to eclipse https://github.com/google/protobuf-dt
(Not sure if this is needed).

**3.** Open the *protobuf/examples/* directory. Run *add_person.cc* in eclipse
The compiler produces the following error. I am seeing that it is a linking error. but I am not sure where I am going wrong.

```
make all 
Building file: ../src/add_person.cc
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -std=c++11 -I/home/rohan/Downloads/Utilities/protobuf/examples -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -pthread -MMD -MP -MF"src/add_person.d" -o "src/add_person.o" "../src/add_person.cc"
Finished building: ../src/add_person.cc

Building target: add_person
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L/usr/lib64 -pthread -o "add_person"  ./src/add_person.o   -lprotobuf
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: ./src/add_person.o: in function `main':
/home/rohan/eclipse-workspace/add_person/Debug/../src/add_person.cc:81: undefined reference to `tutorial::AddressBook::AddressBook()'
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: /home/rohan/eclipse-workspace/add_person/Debug/../src/add_person.cc:81: undefined reference to `tutorial::AddressBook::~AddressBook()'
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: /home/rohan/eclipse-workspace/add_person/Debug/../src/add_person.cc:81: undefined reference to `tutorial::AddressBook::~AddressBook()'
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: ./src/add_person.o: in function `google::protobuf::internal::GenericTypeHandler<tutorial::Person_PhoneNumber>::New(google::protobuf::Arena*)':
/usr/local/include/google/protobuf/repeated_field.h:656: undefined reference to `tutorial::Person_PhoneNumber* google::protobuf::Arena::CreateMaybeMessage<tutorial::Person_PhoneNumber>(google::protobuf::Arena*)'
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: ./src/add_person.o: in function `google::protobuf::internal::GenericTypeHandler<tutorial::Person>::New(google::protobuf::Arena*)':
/usr/local/include/google/protobuf/repeated_field.h:656: undefined reference to `tutorial::Person* google::protobuf::Arena::CreateMaybeMessage<tutorial::Person>(google::protobuf::Arena*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:47: add_person] Error 1
"make all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.
```

Comment: Have you compiled the protobuf?

Comment: In your example there is a file called 'addressbook.proto'. You are supposed to run that through the protobuf compiler which will generate some C++ source files. You add those files to your project and they will resolve the missing dependencies. How you do that in the context of eclipse I have no idea. You can always just use the command line.

Comment: @john yes I did compile. I added those. *addressbook.pb.cc* and *addressbook.pb.h* these are the file generated from proto file. and include contains that `-I/home/rohan/Downloads/Utilities/protobuf/examples`. Obviously I can use command line, but I have started it with eclipse and This is some problem I have not faced before, so I would love to solve this:)

Comment: There's no evidence from your command line above that you have compiled addressbook.pb.cc. `g++ -std=c++11 -I/home/rohan/Downloads/Utilities/protobuf/examples -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -pthread -MMD -MP -MF"src/add_person.d" -o "src/add_person.o" "../src/add_person.cc"` I would expect to see addressbook.pb.cc in there as well as add_person.cc.

Comment: So, How will the **expected line** look like? I thought that will be handled by `-I` command

Comment: No the `-I` option is for included header files. The problem is that you are not compiling the generated source file. You need to set up your project so that it compiles both add_person.cc and addressbook.pb.cc. I'm sorry but I don't know enough about eclipse to know exactly what the command line would look like, but whatever you did to make add_person.cc compile you need to do for addressbook.pb.cc as well.

Comment: not sure if thats the reason, but if your eclipse is configured to scan the directories and compile all `.cpp` files then you can simply rename the generated `.pc.cc`

Comment: @user463035818 I don't know the reason. But I simply added the files `addressbook.pb.cc` and `addressbook.pb.h` into the eclipse workspace and it worked smooth. I did not have to rename anything. So, earlier when it was not working, the files mentioned were in the **examples** folder of the downloaded repository mentioned in *STEP 1*, and it was simply included in the program with `-I`. So what difference did it make? Would you be willing to explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Please note: This may not solve others' problems.*

The example program that I was running in eclipse only had `add_person.cc` file in the project. And the files containing protocolbuffer classes and definitions (`addressbook.pb.h` & `addressbook.pb.cc`) were not in the project. Instead I added them as `-I\path\to\the\directory\` which produced that error.

For this problem of min I simply had to **move / copy** the `addressbook.pb.h` & `addressbook.pb.cc` files inside the project.